# How to create a USB that copies all photos from PC to which it is connected, using Batch files?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, robocopy, xcopy

I tried doing this, but it is not working

```
:: variables
/min
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
echo off

for /r C:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%drive%\all\pics"

@echo off
cls
```

Comment: Please do not multipost. You already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298559/how-to-create-a-usb-that-copies-all-photos-from-pc-to-which-it-is-connected-usi?noredirect=1#comment44977915_28298559) this question on [SO]

Answer (score 3):

#### I tried doing this, but it is not working

There are a number of issues with your batch file.

---

#### Use of `%`

You need to use `%%` in a batch file. `%` is for a command line.

---

#### Use of /min

```
:: variables
/min
```

`/min` - '/min' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this.

---

#### Use of `odrive`

```
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
```

Is `odrive` already defined? If not is will be set to `~0,2`. In any case it is not used again.

---

#### Use of `backupcmd`

```
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

You don't use `backupcmd`

---

#### Use of `for`

```
echo off

for /r C:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%drive%\all\pics"
```

This is not a valid use of `for`. You need to use `%%f` not `%f`.

`copy` takes at least two parameters, source and destination.

Is `%drive%` already defined?

Try the following `for` command:

```
for /r C:\ %%f in (*.jpg) do @copy %%f "%drive%\all\pics"
```

---

#### The operation of the FOR command can be summarised as...

> - Take a set of data
> - Make a FOR Parameter %%G equal to some part of that data
> - Perform a command (optionally using the parameter as part of the command).
> - Repeat for each item of data
>
> If you are using the FOR command at the command line rather than in a
>   batch program, use just one percent sign: %G instead of %%G.

Source [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).

Answer (score 1):

Try ROBOCOPY command with the /MIR option. It recursively searches through all folders and copies just updated/new files. The source directory structure is recreated at the target. Usage e.g.

```
robocopy /mir <source path> <target path>
```

Comment: What has that to do with photos?

Answer (score 0):

I always think less is better. Why not just try the following?

```
xcopy /c/d/e/f/h/r/y c:\*.jpg .
```

notes:

- /e implies /s
- /i unneeded since destination exists.
- specifies only jpg files
- destination of "." indicates current directory, assuming the bat file is on the USB.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is resurrecting an old thread, but I've found this code all over the internet (it's been copied a lot) with no clear explanation of the nonsensical `%odrive%` initialization and the non-initialization of `%drive%`.

It doesn't work because they left out some code. Here's how to fix it:

Replace:

```
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
```

With:

```
SET odrive=%CD%
SET drive=%odrive:~0,2%
```

The first line gets the current directory as `%odrive%` and the second line strips out the first two characters (e.g., `C:`) and assigns them to `%drive%`

Note the script assumes it's being run from the removable drive. So  you could simply replace all instances of `%drive%` with `.` and it would work just as well.